CMFCTabCtrl redrawing problems in CFormView - doesn't redraw its buttons and tab content after window move or resize
As stated in title I encountered this kind of nasty problem - here I'm providing snippets of code so that anyone can gain insight into the issue. I have found some solution, but maybe there is some better solution as I don't understand the reason why it's happening.
Creation of view in frame window:
BOOL CustomFormulasFrame::OnCreateClient(LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs, CCreateContext * pContext)
{
    pContext->m_pNewViewClass = RUNTIME_CLASS(CustomFormulasView);

    m_pCustomFormulasView = new CustomFormulasView(
        IDD_CUSTOM_FORMULAS_VIEW,
        m_pCustomFormulasFrameController->GetCustomFormulasViewController());
    if (!m_pCustomFormulasView
             ->Create(nullptr, nullptr, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, CRect(0, 0, 500, 500), this, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST, pContext))
    {
        TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: Could not create custom formulas view.\n");
        return false;
    }

    SetActiveView(m_pCustomFormulasView);
    return true;
}

Constructor of view - note that CCswFormView is not culprit - I have tried it with pure CFormView too:
CustomFormulasView::CustomFormulasView(
    UINT nIDTemplate,
    const std::shared_ptr<ICustomFormulasViewController> & pCustomFormulasViewController)
    : CCswFormView(nIDTemplate),
      m_pController(pCustomFormulasViewController)
{
    ASSERT(pCustomFormulasViewController);
}

Replacement of target area with CMFCTabCtrl, addition of dynamic layout and tab widgets:

BOOL CustomFormulasView::Create(
    LPCTSTR lpszClassName,
    LPCTSTR lpszWindowName,
    DWORD dwStyle,
    const RECT & rect,
    CWnd * pParentWnd,
    UINT nID,
    CCreateContext * pContext)
{
    if (!__super::Create(lpszClassName, lpszWindowName, dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID, pContext))
        return FALSE;

    // Create good tab control on tab control target
    auto pTabControlTarget = GetDlgItem(IDC_CUSTOM_FORMULAS_TABLE_TABS);
    CHECKRF(pTabControlTarget);
    pTabControlTarget->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
    pTabControlTarget->SetDlgCtrlID(0);
    CRect tabControlRect;
    pTabControlTarget->GetWindowRect(&tabControlRect);
    ScreenToClient(tabControlRect);
    m_tabControl.Create(nullptr, nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, tabControlRect, this, 0);
    m_tabControl.SetLocation(CCswMFCTabCtrl::LOCATION_TOP);
    m_tabControl.SetDlgCtrlID(IDC_CUSTOM_FORMULAS_TABLE_TABS);
    auto pDynLayout = GetDynamicLayout();
    pDynLayout->AddItem(m_tabControl, CMFCDynamicLayout::MoveNone(), CMFCDynamicLayout::SizeHorizontalAndVertical(100, 100));

    // Add tabs
    m_pResultTableTabWindow = CreateCustomFormulasListWidget(ECustomFormulaTable::Results, &m_tabControl);
    m_pSummaryTableTabWindow = CreateCustomFormulasListWidget(ECustomFormulaTable::Summary, &m_tabControl);

    m_tabControl.AddTab(m_pResultTableTabWindow.get(), IDS_CUSTOM_FORMULA_TARGET_RESULT_TABLE, 0, false);
    m_tabControl.AddTab(m_pSummaryTableTabWindow.get(), IDS_CUSTOM_FORMULA_TARGET_SUMMARY_TABLE, 0, false);

    return TRUE;
}

std::shared_ptr<CustomFormulasListWidget> CustomFormulasView::CreateCustomFormulasListWidget(
    ECustomFormulaTable eCustomFormulaTable,
    CWnd * pParentWnd)
{
    auto tabControllers = m_pController->GetTabControllersForTab(eCustomFormulaTable);
    CHECKRX(tabControllers.m_pListWidgetController != nullptr, {});
    auto pListWidget = std::make_shared<CustomFormulasListWidget>(tabControllers.m_pListWidgetController, pParentWnd);
    auto pRedrawble = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<IRedrawableController>(tabControllers.m_pListWidgetController);
    CHECKRX(pRedrawble != nullptr, {});
    pRedrawble->SetRedrawable(pListWidget);
    pListWidget->Create(CustomFormulasListWidget::IDD, pParentWnd);

    return pListWidget;
}

CustomFormulasListWidget is derived from CDialog. Note that deriving it from CFormView doesn't help the issue at all.
Found fix for inside of tabs and for CMFCTabCtrl:
void CustomFormulasView::OnPaint()
{
    __super::OnPaint();
    // CFormView with combination of CMFCTabCtrl doesn't redraw inside of the tab after window move or resize
    auto pActiveWindow = m_tabControl.GetActiveWnd();
    if (pActiveWindow)
        pActiveWindow->RedrawWindow();
}

void CCswMFCTabCtrl::OnPaint()
{
    __super::OnPaint();
    // For some reason drop-down button is not repainted when using this control in CFormView after view window is
    // resized or moved. This fixes it.
    m_btnScrollRight.RedrawWindow();

   // Similarly redraw other buttons from CMFCTabCtrl implementation, we use the layout with top-right drop-down button
}

Is there any better solution. Am I doing something wrong?
